# How to use XMLSlurper and setKeepIgnorableWhiteSpace()

Tags: grails, groovy, xmlslurper

I have a piece of Grails code which is downloading an XML file, parsing it, making some changes, then writing it back again.

```
def xmlFile = simpleSftpService.downloadFile('theFile.xml')    
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
rootNode.someThing.each(){
    it.thingy='It should be this'
}

def fileName="MyNew.xml"
File writer = File.createTempFile('tempFile', '.xml')
def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
        writer << builder.bind {
            mkp.yield rootNode
        }
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(writer))
def storeFile = simpleSftpService.uploadFile(inputStream, fileName)
```

This all works fine, except I lose all the whitespace in the resultant file. So to overcome this I am trying to use the following code :-

```
def rootNode= new XmlSlurper()
rootNode.setKeepIgnorableWhiteSpace(true)
rootNode.parse(xmlFile)
```

Which doesn't work in that it produces null.  So I tried :-

```
def rootNode=XmlSlurper()setKeepIgnorableWhiteSpace(true).parse(xmlFile)
```

but that gives me an error :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method parse() on null object
```

How can I use setKeepIgnorableWhiteSpace() to keep the formatting in my XML?

Comment: What you first tried (creating new, setting property, then parsing) seems valid to me.  `setKeepIgnorableWhiteSpace()` returns void, so you definitely can't chain the calls.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, thats what I though too.  But using my first example, when it gets to the rootNode.someThing.each()  line it errors out with  -  No such property: someThing for class: groovy.util.XmlSlurper.     It seems the result of the parsing is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
slurper.setKeepIgnorableWhiteSpace(true)
def rootNode = slurper.parse(xmlFile)
rootNode.someThing?.each { ...
...etc.
```

Problem was that you were setting `rootNode` to the XmlSlurper rather than to the results of the parse.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. That does indeed work splendidly.